# Find out if REPLACE statement has replaced or just inserted in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to find out if the last REPLACE statement actually replaced any row or just performed a regular insert?
`LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesn't seem to help, since the autoincrement counter is updated in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) returns the count of affected rows. This can be retrieved in SQL by `ROW_COUNT()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to determine the `affected rows` count. `REPLACE` doesn't update rows; it inserts or deletes and then inserts.

From the MySQL manual:

> The affected-rows count makes it easy to determine whether REPLACE only added a row or whether it also replaced any rows: Check whether the count is 1 (added) or greater (replaced).

Check out the manual page: [MySQL REPLACE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which rows have been effacted, you can also write a delete trigger that writes deleted rows to a history table.

Or let the delete trigger count the rows deleted and select it at the end of the query.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER t_yourtable_d AFTER DELETE
ON yourtable 
BEGIN
  SET @int = IFNULL(@int,0)+1;
END$$
```

when you are done inserting just do a

```
SELECT @int;
```

And you will get the number of rows that have been replaced. Of course this only makes sense if your query inserts/replaces more that just one row, i.e.

```
REPLACE INTO a(ax,ay,az) 
SELECT bx, by, bz 
FROM b;
```

Comment: Well the code that I posted will not tell you exaclty which rows have been modified, but it will tell you how many rows have been REPLACED when you insert multiple rows at once.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. That's a good idea if you care about the number of rows replaced.