# Check if INSERT or REPLACE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

On running a query in java using JDBC with MySQL:

```
replace into orders(external_id, channel_id) values ("1001","test");
```

I want to get if the order was inserted or replaced in DB.

Comment: iuse: INSERT INTO ....... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148611/find-out-if-replace-statement-has-replaced-or-just-inserted-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html):

> The affected-rows count makes it easy to determine whether REPLACE
>   only added a row or whether it also replaced any rows: Check whether
>   the count is 1 (added) or greater (replaced).

So you can use the `ROW_COUNT()` to get the number of row which are affected after executing the query. Replace will not update the `ROW_COUNT()` when it will change the existing row.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
INSERT INTO orders(external_id, channel_id) VALUES("1001","test") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE external_id="1001", channel_id="test"
```