# How to see if mysql replace or insert my query

Tags: php, mysql, replace, insert

if I have a query with field 1 being a primary key:

```
$rep = "Replace into table (field1,field2) values ('value1','value2')";
$stmt = $db->query($rep);
```

Is there a way to tell if mysql inserted the row, or found and replaced the row?

Comment: already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16148611/6385306,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/6385306

Comment: You can use `mysqli_info()` function.

Comment: `$stmt->affected_rows` should have a value of 1 on insert or greater than 1 on replace (assuming `$db` is a mysqli connection link)

Answer (score 1):

For Posterity:

```
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
```

if $rowCount == 1 it was an insert, if $rowCount == 2, it was a replace.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO AggregatedData (datenum,Timestamp)
VALUES ("734152.979166667","2010-01-14 23:30:00.000")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  Timestamp=VALUES(Timestamp)

To achieve this type of task mysql provide us `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Below is the example how you will create new record if record is not exists in database otherwise it will update record

```
$rep = "INSERT into table (primaryField,field2) values ('value1','value2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE primaryField=VALUES(primaryField)";
$stmt = $db->query($rep);
```

> For more detail you can read this 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

I think this will help you.